# Accessing a hasMany relation function via Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am trying to get all of the users notifications, and depending on if the user is a buyer or seller (can be both). I have made two functions in my notifications table to filter each other out.
My goal is to ultimately run:

```
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->getBuyerNotifications();
```

or

```
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->getSellerNotifications();
```

I am running into an issue: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany`

**User Model:**

```
public function notifications() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**Notifications Model:**

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}

public static function getBuyerNotifications() {
  return self::whereNotNull('buyer_id')
              ->whereNull('deleted_at')
              ->get();

}

public static function getSellerNotifications() {
      return $this->whereNotNull('seller_id')
                    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->get();
}
```

The command I want to run to get all of the users notifications if they're a buyer: `$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->getBuyerNotifications();`

Comment: Why are those static methods?

Comment: @jeremykenedy Was testing something out - no need for it to be static

Comment: Just curious, does the error happen when you have just `$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications` ?

Comment: @jeremykenedy No Error. Just returns a collection of notifications

Comment: @jeremykenedy now I could do notifications()->whereNotNull('buyer_id') etc. in one line but having it in a function would be ideal so anyone can just call it

Comment: Do you have the user id available?

Comment: @jeremykenedy Yes the user_id is set and the notifications it returns is for the current user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to use `whereNull('deleted_at')`, you can import the [softDeletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting) Trait in your model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
...
class Notification extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    ...
}
```

Laravel will automatically use `whereNull('deleted_at')` on Eloquent-Builder.

Secondly, you cannot use static method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany`.

Use [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) method instead:

```php
public function scopeBuyerNotifications($query) {
    return $query->whereNotNull('buyer_id');
}
public function scopeSellerNotifications($query) {
    return $query->whereNotNull('seller_id');
}
```

So you can find the notification like this:

```php
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->sellerNotifications()->get();

$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->buyerNotifications()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` uses session data.

Try this:

```
optional(User::find(Auth::id())->notifications)->getBuyerNotifications;
```

or

```
$userId = 1; // Example id you can just pass the user Id.
User::find($userId)->notifications->getBuyerNotifications;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two other methods in user model as follows

```
public function getBuyerNotifications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'buyer_id', 'id');
}
public function getSellerNotifications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'seller_id', 'id');
}
```

And you can call it directly from the user instance

```
$user->getBuyerNotifications();
$user->getSellerNotifications();
```